# How can I change npm version while using create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to run create-react-app in my command line, and I keep getting this message:

"You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be boostrapped with an old unsupported version of tools."

I ran

> sudo npm install npm@latest -g

to make sure I have the latest version of npm (I also tried "sudo npm install -g npm"). And when I run

> npm -v

the output is "6.4.1"

I get a number of errors during the create-react-app process,  but the app itself seems to work fine, "npm start" works and all the files seem to be in the right place, but I don't want to run into more errors down the road.

After a couple hours of searching, I can't find any other issues of create-react-app using the wrong version of npm. Is there a way to change the version of npm being used while using create-react-app?

The hidden code snippet below lists the errors that I get during create-react-app. I feel like they might be due to using the outdated version of npm.

```html
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.17/fse-v1.0.17-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.17 and node@11.0.0 (node-v67 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.17/fse-v1.0.17-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.17 and node@11.0.0 (node-v67 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 

gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/myuser/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:285:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.4.0
 
gyp ERR! node -v v11.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I believe I had some extra node files floating around (potentially from installations I didn't do correctly). I decided to do a complete removal of nvm/node/npm and get a fresh install (I am on a mac).

To remove nvm and node, I removed all node and node_package files in /usr (there are quite a few tutorials on where to find node files and folders). I followed the guides but also had a few exceptions. I had a folder that was simply named "n" that had some node files in it (which I then deleted) and then had to show my hidden files to find an ".nvm" folder in /users/userName. I deleted the ".nvm" folder and was finally able to completely get rid of nvm, node and npm.

After I freshly installed nvm and node (I had to remake the .nvm folder for the nvm install script to work), the create-react-app command is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your npm version using this:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Please note that this command will remove your current version of npm. Make sure to use

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

if on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the reply divakar! I tried using `sudo npm install -g npm` (I am on a Mac), which ran without any issues. I'm still getting "6.4.1" when i run `npm -v`, and getting the same "You are using npm 2.15.12" when running `npx create-react-app`. Any other ideas to get npx create-react-app to use the correct npm version?